# Class Not Found Exception when downloaded from Play Store

Tags: java, android

I've got a problem involving Class Not Found Exception. When i "Run as android application" from Android Studio it works fine, but when i download it from Google Play it crashes with the following stack trace

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app-1/split_config.tr.apk", zip file "/data/app/-1/split_config.xxxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3615) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:221) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1876) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120) Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementInstallReferrerReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/-1/split_config.tr.apk", zip file "/data/app/-1/split_config.xxxhdpi.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]] at
```

MyGradle

---

```
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 71
    versionName "3.7.1"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    multiDexEnabled true

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
}
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
lintOptions {
    checkReleaseBuilds false
    abortOnError false
}
```

}

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.0.0'
```

}

Comment: I have the same issue, What was the problem???? @Muhammad5415

Comment: The solution that the friend said below worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play-services-ads 18.0.0 get crash > 17.2.1 use the

Comment: Please accept the correct answer if your problem is resolved. :)